# Marklogic How can I find out list documents have Key Mismatch

Tags: marklogic

I have some documents return "Key mismatch" errors.

```
fn:doc("/city/010101.xml)

 result:
 [1.0-ml] XDMP-KEYMISMATCH: fn:doc("/city/010101.xml") -- Key mismatch, 
 CacheExpandedTreeStorage::put , uniqKey1=0x2c0d120d2ada6c2a5, uniqKey2=0xa5a9ab1b8021df93e10, uriKey1=0x8ac46966e011159b0d, uriKey2=0xfa38e13b022c1f5115
```

It looks like there are lost file data from the storage or file system layer.

> Indexed32FileSequentialReader::read: XDMP-READ: /data/Forests/-05-A/0000df03/TreeData: Invalid read

How can I loop through over two million records to find out which documents have keyMismatch?

Loop through collection but I don't know what query to tell MarkLogic retrieves documents have Key mismatch uniqKey issues.

```
let $u := cts:uris((),(),
                cts:and-query(cts:collection-query("/city"))
          )
 return ($u)
```

Comment: You're going to need official support for this. That's an issue at the C++ layer.

Comment: It looks like there are lost file data from the storage or file system layer.Indexed32FileSequentialReader::read: XDMP-READ: /data/Forests/-05-A/0000df03/TreeData: Invalid read