# Marklogic fragment

Tags: marklogic

I run script to scan all documents in collections, then throw exception some URI documents are not found.  is that mean Marklogic tried to read a document that has fragment on the disk, then fragement returns none. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to your previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902549/marklogic-how-can-i-find-out-list-documents-have-key-mismatch ... and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970860/marklogic-how-to-continue-looping-after-throw-catching-exception ... Generally speaking, if you return a URI from cts:uris you should be able to open it. It sounds like you're encountering some pretty serious system failure. Are you in touch with MarkLogic Support?

Comment: yes that's correct. I try to understand basic knowledge before I in touch ML support. Thanks

Comment: Directories would have a uri, but no document fragment. That is not exceptional, but would mean you either have auto-creation enabled, or dirs were created manually somehow. Check if the uri ends with `/`..